# Oracle SQL. Data range in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have SELECT which exports sale info(date, number) between two dates.

```
SELECT SALE_DATE, SALE_NUM
from SALES
where sale_date between '&fromdate' AND '&todate';
```

But I wanna make this with procedure. How to do it? What I have tried:

```
create or replace procedure SALE_DATES(var_saledate in SALES.SALE_DATE%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE Cursor c4 IS
SELECT SALE_DATE, SALE_NUM
from SALES
where sale_date = var_saledate AND var_saledate between '&fromdate' AND '&todate';
BEGIN FOR item IN c4

  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
     ('Date= ' || item.sale_date || ', Sale number: ' || item.sale_num);
  END LOOP;
  END;
  END;
```

start of the procedure:

```
begin SALE_DATES(.....);
end;
```

What parameter should I use in the braces?

Comment: I think you are going to need to pass two parameters into your Procedure : P_from_date and P_to_date.  Then you can just use WHERE sale_date BETWEEN P_from_date AND P_to_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two parameters so you can pass in your date range...  I've used more standard naming conventions and laid it out a little clearer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_sales
 (P_from_date  IN  DATE
 ,P_to_date    IN  DATE
 )
AS

  CURSOR C_get_sales
  IS
    SELECT
     s.sale_date
    ,s.sale_num
    FROM
     sales     s
    WHERE s.sale_date BETWEEN P_from_date AND P_to_date
  ;

BEGIN

  FOR R_this_sale IN C_get_sales LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
     ('Date= ' || R_this_sale.sale_date || ', Sale number: ' || R_this_sale.sale_num)
    ;
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: How do you call the procedure? I tried with begin SALE_DATES('&from_Date','&to_date');
end; but their is nothing in the DBMS output edit: Sorry, I forgot set serveroutput on;

Answer (score 1):

```
   SQL> set serveroutput on; -- for dbms_output.put_line to take effect

   SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SALE_DATES( v_sale_date_from 
   sales.sale_date%type,  v_sale_date_to sales.sale_date%type )
    AS
     Cursor c4 IS
     select SALE_DATE, SALE_NUM
       from SALES
      where sale_date between v_sale_date_from  AND v_sale_date_to ;
    BEGIN
    FOR item IN c4

      LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Date= ' || item.sale_date || ', Sale number: ' || item.sale_num);
      END LOOP;
    END;/


    SQL> exec SALE_DATES(to_date('&dt1','dd.mm.yyyy'),to_date('&dt2','dd.mm.yyyy'));/ 
     -- assuming your nls_date_format is dd.mm.yyyy, when prompted enter 19.12.2017 as an example.
```